# В чем разница между colorAccent и android:colorAccent?

Tags: java, android, android-style, android-themes

В чем разница между colorAccent и android:colorAccent?

> В Стилях и в xml разметке часто встречается такая вещь как background
>   и android:background

И в чем разница между

> Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button и Widget.AppCompat.Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что начинается с пространства имен `android:` - системные ресурсы. То, что без пространства имен - ресурсы проекта.

В частности ресурс `colorAccent` относится к стилю *Material*, данный стиль доступен в системе с API 21. То есть, на API 21 и выше вы обращаетесь к ресурсу системы через `android:colorAccent`, а на API < 21 вы используете библиотеку *AppCompat* для реализации стиля *Material* - подключенные в проект внешние библиотеки при этом так же являются ресурсами проекта, а не системы и к ним вы обращаетесь через `colorAccent` (этот ресурс находится в библиотеке *AppCompat*)

Base в стилях - основа для подстилей (например светлой и темной темы), то что одинаково для всех вариантов подстилей.

Comment: Ничего не понял. То без пространство вы сказали ресурсы проекта. Но их нет. Они также берутся из Android ресурсов. Тот же background и android:background

Comment: приведите в вопросе код, который вам не понятен (с background и android: background). Я с трудом понимаю, что именно вы хотите узнать, а после комментария еще меньше.

Comment: @pavlofff, кажется вопрос в том зачем `colorAccent` и `android:colorAccent` сделаны и когда нужно использовать первый вариант и когда второй. Вроде тут дело в обратной совместимости и без пространства имён андроида можно использовать с 21 АПИ

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, кажется понял, только наоборот - до API 21 :)

Comment: Тоесть если я пишу приложение с target от 17 версии допустим. То использовать android:colorAccent?

А если с 21 версии то colorAccent?


Но допустим backgroundTint в xml не поддерживается в некоорызх компонетах. К примеру EditText и чо тогда делать?

Comment: @xTIGRx если внимательно почитать, что я написал, то наоборот все.

Comment: @pavlofff, `android:colorAccent = 21 и выше?` и `colorAccent= меньше 21?`

Comment: @xTIGRx  да __________